# How to compare date in string with sysdate in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, comparison

I am new with Oracle and still get used to SQL Server.

I do not understand on why the command below would return '1' when clearly sysdate which is today is 29-Apr-15 that clearly before 30-Apr-15

It should return 0. But I do not understand why it returns 1.

Any ideas? Thanks =)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sysdate > to_date('30-Apr-15','DD-MON-YYYY') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
    FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing the century from your date

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sysdate > to_date('30-Apr-2015','DD-MON-YYYY') THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
    FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you. Good catch. I really miss that one.

Answer (score 2):

Because you have used `15` instead of `2015`. You need to be aware of the **Y2K** bug. Using 'YY' format for year in a DATE is a bad idea. Always try to use **'YYYY'** when converting a string into **DATE**

Or else, use the **`RR`** format to overcome the Y2K issue.

For example,

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('30-Apr-15','DD-MON-RR') RR,
  2         TO_DATE('30-Apr-15','DD-MON-YYYY') YY
  3  FROM DUAL;

RR         YY
---------- ----------
04/30/2015 04/30/0015

SQL>
```

Using the same in your query:

```
SQL> SELECT
  2    CASE
  3      WHEN sysdate > to_date('30-Apr-15','DD-MON-RR')
  4      THEN '1'
  5      ELSE '0'
  6    END
  7  FROM DUAL
  8  /

C
-
0

SQL>
```